# Quickblox getUsersByFilter with multiple parameters

Tags: android, quickblox

How to perform multiple filtering in QBUsers Request? For example, now I'm requesting users with login equals 9634.

```
public void getUsers(){
    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(100);


    ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList();
    userId.add("9634");
    QBUsers.getUsersByFilter(userId, "string login eq ", pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle bundle) {
            for (int i = users.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                QBUser user = new QBUser();
                user.setLogin(users.get(i).getLogin());
                user.setId(users.get(i).getId());
                user.setCustomData(users.get(i).getCustomData());
                userslist.add(user);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });
```

}

What should i change to make request based on multiple filters? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after reading QuickBlox docs i found that it is possible use only one filter when querying users and multiple filters when querying CustomObjects. So as i suggest the only way to filter users by custom parameters is to receive QBUsers array and filter it manually like.

```
private void getUsers(int page, final String... params){
    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(page);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(100);


    ArrayList<Integer> userId = new ArrayList();
    userId.add(8776861);
    QBUsers.getUsersByFilter(userId, "number id ne ", pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle bundle) {
            for (int i = users.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                QBUser user = new QBUser();
                user.setLogin(users.get(i).getLogin());
                user.setId(users.get(i).getId());
                user.setCustomData(users.get(i).getCustomData());
                if (Utils.userdataint(users.get(i).getCustomData(),"age")>9&&
                        Utils.userdata(users.get(i).getCustomData(),"city").contains(params[0])
                        ){
                    userslist.add(user);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });}
```

Also it is possible to use getUsersByTags to receive users with multiple tags but in most cases it's not an answer.